# How to test Dart code snippet in Flutter development?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

#### Description:

- I'm new to Android Studio and Flutter, and try to write App with.
  Currently I have to build App on device in order to test some code snippet, and it's inefficient.
- Is there a way to test code snippet in console, like Python Console or JavaScript Console in browser?

#### For example:

- Assuming I'm not sure how datetime manipulation work in Python, and then I write some code in PyCharm IDE to test out:
- [image: Test some code in PyCharm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two easy ways as I know for this situation.

First is in browser solution; DartPad https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Second is in Android Studio;

[image]

Create a test.dart file under your project folder. Click down arrow near main.dart seen in image. Select "Edit Configurations". Then new screen pops up. Click + sign and "Dart Command Line App". Browse and select your test.dart file. Click apply and close window. Now you can run your test.dart file and see results in console.

Comment: Does the approach at Android Studio also work on other languages, such as Kotlin and etc?

Comment: There is "Kotlin script" option on configuration menu but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your code on android studio terminal, there is no need tempering with your configurations. Make sure you are in the same folder with the testing.dart. Then run `dart testing.dart`